# Vote down or delete low quality content?

Tags: discussion, comments, low-quality, down-votes

Several answers are of very low quality or some only include links.

I often see users are flagging them for beeing low quality. There are basicly three things I can do as a moderator:

1. leave a comment to educate the users and try to convince him to improve his answer.
2. vote down to indicate this is a post of low quality.
3. delete the post (or convert it to a comment).

If you flag a low quality post, what do you want a moderator to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will answer my own question and want to suggest the following. Post another answer if you disagree.

1. Leaving a comment - anyone with at least **50 reputation** can do this. If you see posts which could be improved: **Leave a comment.** Don't flag it.
2. Downvoting - anyone with at least **125 reputation** can do this. If you see posts of low quality: **Vote down.** Posts of score -3 and less will be grayed out and auto-deleted. Don't flag it.
3. Deletion - only moderators can delete posts. Users with **4000 reputation** can cast delete votes. However, please follow the guide from the [help center](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user):

> #### When should I flag or vote to delete an answer?
>
> You may vote to delete answers in the following cases:
>
> - The answer is **extremely** low quality: There is little to no scope for improvement
> - The answer doesn't attempt to answer the question; it may be a comment or a separate question altogether.

Keep in mind the site is run *by you* as the community. Ideally, moderators should do as little as possible.

You got the tools. Use them wisely.

Comment: Addendum to 1., if you have a concrete idea how to improve the post, suggest an edit. Also, if I were to put a VLQ flag on something, I'd likely also downvote it at the same time.

Comment: I like your 3 suggestions.  I would personally want to add: ideally, leaving a comment would always be everyone's first move (even if one has the capacity to down vote), especially with new users.  If (a) the low quality answer already has a comment to improve that is at least a week old, or (b) the person who posted that answer is a repeat offender, then I think down voting (for those who can) or flagging (for those who cannot down vote) is the best way to go.  I like to be part of communities where we give each other a chance to learn and grow rather than have a punitive first response.

Comment: Yes these options are not mutually exclusive. Thanks for your comment. I'm also no friend of deleting very low quality content.